Issue searching down columns
In SQL server 2016 I have a table, let's say like this:



ID.
Number
details




1
02
Temp


1
03
Temp/01


2
04
Temp/04



How would I write an update script to use the last 2 digits of the details column to update all number columns where the ID is the same? Is this even possible?
I used:
Update Table
Set Number = RIGHT(details, 02)
Where number NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', details)

But obviously that didn't work so I added a:
AND details LIKE '%/%'

To sort out the details columns without a number at the end.
However this isn't really a solution as it leaves columns with matching ID's but different number values

WHERE number <> RIGHT(details, 2) AND details LIKE '%/%' maybe?

Are you aware that SQL Server 2008 went out of support 5 years ago?

The question says where the ID is the same. What's the desired result? Change number for just the two rows to 01? Clear out the first and change the second to 01? Should the third row be modified? If ID isn't unique what's the actual primary key? This may matter

You can use COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) to find how many rows have the same ID, and update only those that have a count>1.

To the question above, the desired result would be the first two rows should change to 01 and the last row would stay the same. The actual primary key would in this case just be another main ID field, I didn't think it important to this example

Reading between the lines, seems like you could use conditional (windowed) aggregation and an updatable CTE here:
USE Sandbox;
GO

SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,'02','Temp'),
            (1,'03','Temp/01'),
            (2,'04','Temp/04'))V([ID.],Number,Details) --ID. is a poor choice for a column name; "." characters should not be in names
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [ID.],
           Number,
           Details,
           MAX(CASE WHEN Details LIKE '%/[0-9][0-9]' THEN RIGHT(Details,2) END) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID.]) AS Suffix
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET Number = Suffix;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;


Use This...
WITH cte_table AS (
SELECT Details,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS default_null_or_number,
Details AS details_minus_counting, 1 AS charactor_Counting -- for starting search by First Charactor 
FROM  User_Table

UNION ALL
SELECT Details,
CASE WHEN Substring(details_minus_counting, 1, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' --FEACH NUMBER

THEN isnull(default_null_or_number, '') + Substring(details_minus_counting, 1, 1) 
ELSE default_null_or_number END,
Substring(details_minus_counting, 2, len(details_minus_counting) - 1),
charactor_Counting + 1 --> Loop

FROM cte_table     WHERE len(details_minus_counting) > 0 -->Finish when Char Counting 0.

)

SELECT a.Details, a.default_null_or_number from cte_table a inner join
(
SELECT Details,max(len(default_null_or_number)) final_numeric_value 
FROM cte_table where default_null_or_number is not null group by Details
) b on a.details=b.Details and  len(a.default_null_or_number)=b.final_numeric_value 


